# How to prevent adding identical records to SQL database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am writing a program that recovers structured data as individual records from a (damaged) file and collects the results into a sqlite database.

The program is invoked several times with slightly different recovery parameters. That leads to recovering often the same, but sometimes different data from the file.

Now, every time I run my program with different parameters, it's supposed to add just the newly (different) found items to the same database.

That means that I need a fast way to tell if each recovered record is already present in the DB or not, in order to add them only if they're not existing in the DB yet.

I understand that for each record I want to add, I could first do a SELECT for all columns to see if there is already a matching record in the DB, and only add the new one if no same is found.

But since I'm adding 10000s of records, doing a SELECT for each of these records feels pretty inefficient (slow) to me.

I wonder if there's a smarter way to handle this? I.e, is there a way I can tell sqlite that I do not want duplicate entries, and so it automatically detects and rejects them? I know about the UNIQUE modifier, but that's not it because it applies to single columns only, doesn't it? I'd need to be able to say that the combination of COL1+COL2+COL3 must be unique. Is there a way to do that?

Note: I never want to update any existing records. I only want to collect a set of different records.

***Bonus part - performance***

In a classic programming language, I'd use a key-value dictionary where the key is the sum of all a record's values. Similarly, I could calculate a Hash code for each added record and look that hash code up first. If there's no match, then the record is surely not in the DB yet; If there is a match I'd still have to search the DB for any duplicates. That'd surely be faster already, but I still wonder if sqlite can make this more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use UNIQUE column constraint or to declare a multiple columns unique constraint you can use [UNIQUE () ON CONFLICT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) :

```
CREATE TABLE name ( id int , UNIQUE (col_name1 type , col_name2 type) ON CONFLICT IGNORE )
```

*SQLite has two ways of expressing uniqueness constraints: PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE. Both of them create an index and so the lookup happens through the created index.*

Comment: What about the performance? Will it just search all items individually or will it use some smarter (faster) algorithm, e.g. like using a hash to speed this up?

Comment: Also UNIQUE with multiple column: [For each UNIQUE constraint on the table, each row must feature a unique combination of values in the columns identified by the UNIQUE constraint.](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann for the lookup it is a matter if you have an index on that column, you could speed up the lookup for sure ...

Comment: Yes, I understand the index. But the question is: Does the unique-testing procecure just look up each column via the index, until it has found a mismatch? Or can it do more? I wonder if I should still use the hash code additionally. Or maybe that's overkill. I could test this, but I wonder if someone can tell me the details beforehand.

Comment: So, that means that by using UNIQUE I do not have to add a separate INDEX instruction to the table creation, then? That's nice.

Comment: Yes, the index is created and used for the lookup automatically by SQLite

Comment: One more thing that worries me about in the sqlite docs on the UNIQUE constraint: "for the purposes of UNIQUE constraints NULL values are considered distinct from all other values (including other NULLs)". Does that mean that if I insert the same record twice, and if that insert leaves a column as NULL, then I still get two records added because NULL never matches another NULL? In that case, I'd have to insert my own code for NULL values to prevent this, I guess.

Comment: I tried, using the example from @Sp.: If I insert multiple times with "insert into foo (a) values(2);" then I get dupes. So I did read the spec right, and one must not allow NULLs to be inserted this way. I think this should be added to your answer (it's too far hidden in this discussion now) so that it becomes more complete. Would you please do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sqlite> create table foo (
   ...>         a int,
   ...>         b int,
   ...>         unique(a, b)
   ...> );
sqlite>
sqlite> insert into foo values(1, 2);
sqlite> insert into foo values(2, 1);
sqlite> insert into foo values(1, 2);
Error: columns a, b are not unique
sqlite>
```

Comment: Okay, that explains the syntax. How about the performance? See my comment to @aleroot

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann, I can't help with the performance part, I've never used sqlite in heavy used application.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use an SQL approach (as mentioned in other answers) you can do a select for all your data when the program starts, store the data in a dictionary and work with the dictionary do decide which records to insert to your DB.

The benefit of this approach is the single select is much faster than many small selects.
The disadvantage is that it won't work well if you don't have enough memory to store your data in.

Comment: While that's not a bad idea, I'm afraid I might indeed run out of memory. Hence storing the records one after one in the database in the first place. *If* I should use the hashing approach, I could use your suggestion to store these hashes in local memory at the app start, though. Unless that's overkill as looking up the hashes is just as fast in the DB.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann - From my unrelated tests, accessing the memory is much faster than accessing the DB (as long as the memory is not cached to the disk).

Comment: Well... the same goes for the sqlite db, though. If the engine is well-written (and I assume it is), it'd using memory-mapped file I/O, letting the file be accessed like memory (which could be swapped from and to disk the same as your app main memory). And a db index is nothing more than a (sorted) binary tree. Which is similar to what programming languages (i.e. their support libraries) use for some kinds of key-value dictionaries (e.g. the C++ STL std::map works similarly). There's still some overhead for parsing the SQL cmd and such, though.